# $stateProvider resolve dependency on controller not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router and trying to use resolve with no success. 
Here is my app.js state looks

```
.state('addInvestment', {
    url: '/addUpdateInvestment',
    templateUrl: 'js/angular/modules/investment/views/AddUpdateInvestment.html',
    resolve: {
        InvestmentTypes: ["investmentService", function (investmentService) {
            console.log("Resolving dependency...");
            return investmentService.getInvestmentTypes();
        }]
    }
})
```

It calls my service just fine and I know that service returns data just fine because I am using this service on several places in my application.

Here is my controller looks like:

```
angular.module('InvestmentModule')
    .controller('AddUpdateInvestment',
    ['$scope', 'toaster', '$state', '$stateParams', '$wizard', 'investmentService', 'InvestmentTypes',
    function ($scope, toaster, $state, $stateParams, $wizard, investmentService, InvestmentTypes) {
        $scope.modalData = {};
        $scope.modalData.investmentTypes = InvestmentTypes.items;
    }]);
```

When I load page, I see the following in chrome:

[image: Chrome Error displayed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,
After so much of a struggle, I made it working. There was a problem in my service where after getting response, it was calling a method called handleResponse. But that method was a not a return type of factory.. I don't know how does it make any difference if I call it from resolve Vs call it as a regular service in controller. But it was for some reason breaking the resolve.
Here is my old service..

```
angular.module('InvestmentModule').factory('investmentService', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$q', function($rootScope, $http, $q){
    return{

        getInvestmentTypes:function()
        {
            return $http.get(this.webServiceUrl+'getAllInstitutionsForDisplay').then(handleResponse, handleError);
        }
}
function handleSuccess(response)
    {
        return response.data;
    }

    function handleError( response ) {
        // The API response from the server should be returned in a
        // nomralized format. However, if the request was not handled by the
        // server (or what not handles properly - ex. server error), then we
        // may have to normalize it on our end, as best we can.
        if (
            ! angular.isObject( response.data ) ||
            ! response.data.message
        ) {
            return( $q.reject( "An unknown error occurred." ) );
        }
        // Otherwise, use expected error message.
        return( $q.reject( response.data.message ) );
    }
}]);
```

With the new code, I added the code in the handleSucess in the method itself as seen below..

```
 getInvestmentTypes:function()
        {
            return $http.get(this.webServiceUrl+'getAllInstitutionsForDisplay').then(function(response){return response.data}, handleError);
        }
```

I might have to do similar thing for the handleError as well I believe..

BUT it works now beautifully for me.

Only the problem with this approach is that it is breaking the DRY approach.. Any suggestion to improve it will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the comma.
Then, you have to load the controller after the resolve has done. Almost you can try to use that controller in your state, something like this.

```
.state('addInvestment', {
        url:'/addUpdateInvestment',
        controller: 'AddUpdateInvestment as aui',
        templateUrl:'js/angular/modules/investment/views/AddUpdateInvestment.html',
        resolve: {InvestmentTypes: ['investmentService', function(investmentService) {
            console.log("Resolving dependency...");
            return investmentService.getInvestmentTypes();
        }]}, // this will crash if you dont specify other parameter to the state.
    })
```

EDIT:

Check if this fix the problem

```
InvestmentTypes: ['investmentService', // use single quotes
```

EDIT 2:

It seems that the injection in the resolve is like this:

```
resolve: {
    InvestmentTypes: function(investmentService) {
            console.log("Resolving dependency...");
            return investmentService.getInvestmentTypes();
        }
}
```

Please, look at the wiki [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Comment: I tried the suggested solution and it still throws the same error in chrome console.

Comment: I edited, check if the single quotes fix your problem

Comment: Have you make the changes i posted in EDIT 2?

Comment: Yes..I did make the changes you mentioned in Edit 2 and still it doens't want to work.

Comment: Can you made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with all your source code from the controller and the config state? I need to checkout if there are other problem here..

Comment: I created a punkr with my current setup http://plnkr.co/edit/CouqA4faea6syQKwygUC?p=preview but it is not working as expected.. but at least you can get an idea of how I am setup

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem.

In your resolve you have InvestmentTypes in quotation marks

```
resolve: {
    'InvestmentTypes': ['investmentService', function(investmentService){
        return investmentService.getInvestmentTypes();
    }]
}
```

if you change it to be

```
resolve: {
    InvestmentTypes: ['investmentService', function(investmentService){
        return investmentService.getInvestmentTypes();
    }]
}
```

It should work. I've forked your plunker, if you open up the dev console it should log it to the console

http://plnkr.co/edit/KOxgOqsGJcTD1URuHEOn?p=preview

Comment: George, I tried it and I still have the same problem. I tried removing the quotes in the past as well and it didn't work

Comment: @AndyJohnson If you check the Plnkr, there is an "ng-app" tag on the html, have you got this in your project?

Comment: Yes.. My application is 100% angular and so far, other stuff that I did is working just fine. I in fact forgot to add the ng-app on my Plnkr yesterday